Ubuntu Won't load after updating Driver
I tried to update my NIVIDIA Driver and when I tried to reboot my system it took me back to the bootloader. All it says is no bootable device. I tried going to the grub menu but when I press any alt key it just continues loading.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What commands did you use to update your NIVIDIA Driver? Also, What version of Ubuntu are you running? Please run lsb_release -a and Edit your question to include all this information.

Without details of what you're running, we're limited it what help we can provide. Your provided details imply a problem before you initially rebooted your system which caused the issue, but you've not told us exactly what you did to "update my NVIDIA driver", nor do we know what Ubuntu product (is it a Ubuntu Desktop system? or something else), what release, and if a LTS where kernel stack choices exist what you were using.
